# Parse media:content from RSS feed with PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am trying to parse media:content from RSS with PHP and then show it using HTML.

I went through numerous posts on the same topic but since i'm a beginner I couldn't figure it out because the codes were different from mine.

Currently I dont’ have any line that is trying to get the image from xml.

```
<?php
$html = "";
$url = "url.rss";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);

for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++){
    $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
    $link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
    $description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
    $pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;
    $author = $xml->channel->item[$i]->author;


    $html .= "<a href='$link'><h3>$title</h3></a>";
    $html .= "$description";
    $html .= "<p>$pubDate</p>";
    $html .= "<p>$author</p><hr>";

}
echo $html;
?>
```

This is the info I need from the XML file:

```
 <media:content url="www.image.jpg" medium="image" type="image/jpeg"     width="850" height="425" />
```

Thanks!

I expect the PHP file to show the media file.

Comment: How are you getting `url` with your `php` code?

Comment: This is something I want to find out

Comment: Try this: `$url= $xml->channel->item[$i]->url;`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give us more info?
What is the value of '$xml' after you run simplexml_load_file? (did you get the correct data?)

What error message did you get?

**EDIT - according to your comment**

try using

`$xml->channel->item[$i]->children('media', true)->content->attributes();`

The 'media' inside children is the namespace for the 'content' element. 
While the boolean 'true' variable tells the parser to refer the 'media' as a namespace

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I removed the xml file and the media url's. But with the code I provided everything works well. It fetches the title (adds a link to it), describtion, publish date and author name. I don't get any errors with this code. I just don't know how to define the media: content from xml file to php and html.

Comment: So if I understand correctly the line should be as follows

    `$content = $xml->channel->item[$i]->children('media', true)->content->attributes();`

And to display it with HTML the line should be

   `$html .= "$content";`

This would give me an error "Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__toString(): Node no longer exists in /Users/lrakremmis/Documents/Projects/RSS/index.php on line 22"

Comment: This is because `$content` is an Object and you are trying to use it as a string (therefore calling the magic function `__toString()`). Try to look at the content of `$content` and see if you can solve it yourself :)
Let me know if you need more help